# Post multiple dynamic textbox value

Tags: javascript, php

The textbox is dynamically generated using javascript

```
var txtLoop = 1;

function add(type) {

if (txtLoop !=23){
    var element = document.createElement("input");


    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", "");
    element.setAttribute("name", "txtLine" +txtLoop);
    element.setAttribute("id", "txtLine" +txtLoop);

    txtLoop++;
}
```

The question is, how can you post this multiple textbox based on how many textbox created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can you post this multiple textbox

As long as the textbox has a name attribute, you can access the value:

```
$_POST['txtLine1']
$_POST['txtLine2']
$_POST['txtLine3']
// ... etc
```

If you want an array instead, use:

```
element.setAttribute("name", "txtLine[]");
```

Then in your PHP code, this will return you an array of values:

```
$_POST['txtLine']
```

---

```
for ($x=1; $x<=22; $x++) { 
    if (isset($_POST['txtLine'.$x]) && $_POST['txtLine'.$x] != ''){ 
        $txtLine[$x] = $_POST['txtLine'.$x]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I dont quite understand your answer,. sorry..hmm can you please check this http://jsfiddle.net/vUjnC/15/
In that codes,. you can add and delete textbox, that generated multiple textbox has unique id eg. txtLine1, txtLine2, so on. So how can you post these dynamic textbox?

Comment: Opppss sorry, There is no form in that example,. only add and delete of textbox. I know how to post data when the textbox are static..but I really dont know how to post a data from a dynamic textbox. XD

Comment: for ($x=1;$x<=22;$x++) {

 if (!empty($_POST['txtLine'.$x])){

 $txtLine[$x] = $_POST['txtLine'.$x];

 }
}

it is now already posting the data, but when it is null,. it also display the null, how can you remove the null value? hmm

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if it's not this simple but just wrap the inputs in a form and submit the form.